# Cabling issues and tools on topic?

Tags: discussion

As I just had a question of mine put on hold for questionable on-topic-ness, I thought it might be worth discussing the issue here, since I don't think it's adequately handled by the existing rules.

Post in question was:
[Weird PoE power readings on Pockethernet network tester](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52355/)

I think, network cabling and the requisite tools and measurement gear for it should be on-topic here, especially for kit used in installations beyond home scale.. but a lot of this equipment fails the "paid support" exclusion criterion. (Does any vendor below Fluke or Rohde&Schwarz pricing level actually offer support contracts for their test gear?)

I can understand that it'll be tricky to write this exception in a way that it still keeps the "how to wire up my DSL router?" type question out, but that's why I hope to get some suggestions here.